# Perfect numbers between 1 and 1000

Tags: c, while-loop, perfect-numbers

I don't understand why this program doesn't give any output. I just can't see the bug. This is a program to find every perfect number between 1 and 1000. Please help me find the bug. Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int number=1, i, sum=0;

    while(number<=1000){

        for(i=1; i<number; i++){
            if(number%i==0){
                sum+=i;
            }
        }

        if(sum==number){
            printf("%d is perfect\n", numero);
        }
        number++;
    }

    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: Set `sum` to `0` at the begin of the `while` loop.

Comment: @mch But that outputs 6, 28, and 496.  [I don't get it](http://rextester.com/VSFVE45383).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen that's the correct output: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_perfect_numbers

Comment: @user you might want to include a definition for what is a perfect number, just to make your question complete.

Comment: If you try printing an else along with the sum and number, this might have helped you spot the problem.

Comment: Set sum =  0 before for loop and  change numero to number, you can check on [Perfect Number](http://c.net-question.in/c-basic-programs/perfect-numbers-between-1-and-100)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already said, you have to reset the `sum` to zero at the beginning of the loop.
You also have to replace `numero` with `number` (typo).
And to go further, I suggest you to use a for loop instead the while loop, which I find more readable IMHO. The inner for loop can also stop when `i <= number/2` to optimize a bit. Here is my suggestion of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    int sum;

    for(int number = 1;number <= 1000; number++){
        sum = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i <= number/2; i++){
            if (number % i == 0){
                sum += i;
            }
        }

        if (sum == number){
            printf("%d is perfect\n", number);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
6 is perfect
28 is perfect
496 is perfect
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not reset the `sum` in the loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int number=1;

    while(number<=1000){
        int i, sum=0;

        for(i=1; i<number; i++){
            if(number%i==0){
                sum+=i;
            }
        }

        if(sum==number){
            printf("%d is perfect\n", numero);
        }
        number++;
    }

    return 0;

}
```

for the record, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number):

> In number theory, a perfect number is a positive integer that is equal
>   to the sum of its proper positive divisors, that is, the sum of its
>   positive divisors excluding the number itself (also known as its
>   aliquot sum). Equivalently, a perfect number is a number that is half
>   the sum of all of its positive divisors (including itself) i.e. σ1(n)
>   = 2n.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 perfect numbers between 1 and 1000.

```
{6, 28, 496}
```

Your code is mostly correct but you forgot to reset the sum value after each loop iteration.

```
 ...
    }
    number++;
    sum = 0; // set sum to zero at the end of the while loop
  }
```

And also you misspelled the `number` variable as `numero` inside `printf` function.

```
printf("%d is perfect\n", numero);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    int number = 1, sum = 0;

    while(number<=1000){

        sum = 0;
        for(int i = 1; i < number; i++){

            if(number % i == 0){
                sum += i;
            }
        }

        if(sum == number){
            printf("%d is perfect\n", number);
        }
        number++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

reset the value of sum  to 0 and change numero to number in printf